# 「重複」の定義とは何でしょうか？

Tags: 討議, サポート

- [音声再生時のエラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/17215/%E9%9F%B3%E5%A3%B0%E5%86%8D%E7%94%9F%E6%99%82%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC)
- [音声が再生されません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/17264/%E9%9F%B3%E5%A3%B0%E3%81%8C%E5%86%8D%E7%94%9F%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93)

という2つの質問があり、後者は重複としてクローズされました。

内容を見ると、前者の質問は、

> sample.mp3というデータを再生しようとするときに「引数が足りない」というエラーがでてしまいます。

というもので、原因はSwift 2.0でのAPI変更（エラーハンドリングの文法の追加）についての考慮がないことでした。

後者の質問は既に回答が付いている通り、

> mp3を再生するためにAVAudioPlayerのインスタンスを生成してますが、それがどこにも参照されないまま解放されてるのが原因かと思われます。

`AVAudioPlayer`がメモリから解放されると音楽再生も停止するため、プロパティに保持する必要があるのですが、変数のシャドーイングでローカル変数に保持してしまっていたというコーディングミスです。

また、2つ目の質問の背景は、1つ目の質問の回答へのコメントで分かります。

> 大変ありがとうございます。音声再生のコードは完成したのですが、やはり再生をすると、音が流れません。新たに質問を載せませしたので、もしご指摘の点がありましたら、よ‌​ろしお願いいたします。

エラーハンドリングについての問題は解決したものの、音声が流れない現象があったために、新たな質問をしたということは明白です。

両者の内容は明らかに別物で、有益な回答も付いているという状態で、重複として質問をクローズしたモデレータの判断基準が分かりません。

重複の定義とは内容ではなくタイトルで判断されるものなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

5票のクローズ票が集まるとクローズされるというシステム的な物事なので、たとえ、内容的に実際は重複でなくとも、「重複と判断」してしまう人が5票出れば、クローズされることになると思います。

その「判断」の是非に対して、質問者当人は当然として、不服な人は

[重複とマークされている質問があるのはなぜですか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

> 質問が、実際に重複であるということに同意しない場合は、違いを強調するように編集するか、再オープン票を投票するかモデレーターの注意を喚起するため通報するかして、再オープンを試みてください。

という対抗措置も可能なので、参加者同士のコンセンサスによって方向性が定まっていく相対的な結果であり、モデレーターに個々の内容的な是非の判断を委ねるといったスタンスの場ではないと、私は考えています。

つまり、題名などからの心象によって、重複ではないかというフラグが立った時、本人または同意しない人は、実際はそうではないということを、題名を修正するなり、質問を修正して、重複票を投じる可能性がある人の印象を翻意させる努力ができると思います。表現から他人が受ける心象と、内容が乖離している場合は往々にしてあり、それによるギャップを埋める必要性を折り込んで、参加する形になるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 私は、重複クローズの意味合いは「努力を怠ったペナルティ」「質問者や不服な人は対抗しなければならない」というような懲罰的な意味合いのものではなく、「内容が同じ質問と回答がある場合にその情報を集約する」ことが目的だと考えていました。また、今回は5票目がモデレータ（◆ユーザー）でしたが、モデレータがクローズ判断をすれば5票未満でもクローズできます。付け加えると、現在の日本語版SOだと信用度2000があればクローズ票のレビューで他人がどう判断したか知ることができ、私は「オープンのままにする」に投じたので意見が割れていたことも知ることができたので、モデレータがどういう意味合いで重複クローズしたのか問い合わせている次第となります。

Comment: @quesera2 コメントまで確認せず重複と判断してました。判断ミスです。申し訳ありません。クローズを取り消しました。

Comment: @quesera2 ペナルティや懲罰というつもりではないです。いずれにせよ、結果は相対的、流動的なものと考えて参加していくしかないということを言いたかったのです。ja.stackoverflow.comではまだ投稿の流量が少ないので、参加者の間で現状、コンセンサスをある程度単一化することは可能ですが、今後本家のように流量が多くなってくると、それほど中央集権的にモデレーションが維持できるとは思えず、システム的に、そこは割り切りが必要なのではないかという意見でした。メタでの討議なので、個別の案件の是非に踏み込んだ判断（この件では、全く、私は個人的にquesera2さんに同意の立場です）とは別にして、です。ともかく、tomuteさんに伝わった点はよかったと思います。

Comment: @tomute 対応のお手数ありがとうございました。この件については、編集によって両者の差異を強調するなど、コミュニティとしてできることがあったと思っており申し訳ないです（これは言い訳になりますが、クローズ票の入った解決済の質問を新着に上げてしまうと、クローズのリスクが高まるのではと考えて、モデレータ判断で覆ることを期待したのです）

Comment: @hata 重複は別な質問へのリンクとなるので、「内容の違うものが集約されてしまうのは知識の集積の場としてどうなのか？それとも同一に見えるタイトルならばそれでもしょうがない‌​のか？」という意味も含めてこの質問がありました。とはいえ認識の統一というのは簡単なものではなく、割り切りも必要という考えには同意します。また、モデレーターに個々の内容的な是非の判断を委ねるのも、数少ないモデレータに負荷を掛ける行為になりかねないという点で微妙な判断であり、hataさまに示して頂いた、クローズ後に再編集して、通報から再オープンというのが正着だったと思います。